# Recover deleted exchange mailbox after re-creation

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, data-recovery

So here's what happened.
I had a user account that was giving me (unrelated) trouble, so I deleted the user account from the SBS console. I didn't think about it at the time, but the box was checked to `Delete Mailbox`. *Absolutely brilliant*
Anyhow, I recreated the user account and set it up on the domain. *Only later did I realize, how stupid that was.*

**Can I recover the 'old' mailbox, even though a new one was created with the same name?**

- The mailbox is not showing in the `Disconnected Mailbox` under `Recipient Configuration` in the Exchange Management Console
- No emails are showing up on the client, (in outlook) under `Recover Deleted Items`

This is running Exchange 2010

Comment: Lemme guess, no backups either?

Comment: Errrr, um, not really

Comment: Aside from the current issue, what's your plan if you lose business critical data or the server goes belly up?

Comment: [Items Not Showing in Disconnected Mailboxes](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ferris/archive/2010/01/10/deleted-mailbox-not-appearing-in-disconnected-mailbox-gui-read-on.aspx) This has helped me in the past, sometimes things get stuck and using Clean-MailboxDatabase under exchange management shell can help.

Comment: @NickYoung I've already tried that. Still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Surely a bit of google fu here would get you where you need to be. In any case
these 2 links explain what may have gone on.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb125192(v=exchg.141).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb232039(v=exchg.141).aspx

If you disconnect a user from their mailbox you have 30 days to reconnect or it gets removed.

If the 'Delete Mailbox' option you had checked only does a soft delete then you may be able to restore it following the second link.

If not then you are going to have to start a new mailbox.